Connecting PIR sensor to Phidget input
I have bought some of these PIR sensors, which I intend to connect to Phidget inputs (phidgets.com).
The problem is that this sensor has two outputs: ground and 24V and for some reason the output 24V is always connected to input 24V, while it is the ground output that is "broken" when there is no movement. All PIR sensors I have installed before always break the 24V output. So for the old sensors, I use the same ground for everything and connect the 24V output from the sensors to the input connections on the Phidget board.
A Phidget input board operates with the same ground for all input connections. I don't see how I can connect several of these new sensors to a Phidget board? Do I need to install some relay, so that the sensor triggers a relay and then I can detect when this is closed or open?
